# cannot read properties of undefined 'textContent'

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, codeceptjs

I have a simple piece of code

```
describe('My First Puppeeteer Test', () => {
it('Should launch the browser', async function() {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false})
        const page = await browser.newPage()
        await page.goto('https://github.com/login')
        await page.type('#login_field', testLogin)
        await page.type('#password', testPassword)
        await page.click('[name="commit"]')
        await page.waitForNavigation()
        
        let [element] = await page.$x('//h3[@class="text-normal"]')
        let helloText = await page.evaluate(element => element.textContent, element);
        
        console.log(helloText);
        browser.close();
    })
})
```

Everything worked before but today I get an error + my stacktrace:

> Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'textContent')
> at **puppeteer_evaluation_script**:1:21
> at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:221:19)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:110:16)
> at async Context. (tests\example.tests.js:16:22)

How I can resolve this?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't tested the code due to the login and I assume your selectors are correct, the main problem is almost certainly that

```js
await page.click('[name="commit"]')
await page.waitForNavigation()
```

creates a race condition. The [docs](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageclickselector-options) clarify:

> Bear in mind that if `click()` triggers a navigation event and there's a separate `page.waitForNavigation()` promise to be resolved, you may end up with a race condition that yields unexpected results. The correct pattern for click and wait for navigation is the following:
>
> ```js
> const [response] = await Promise.all([
>   page.waitForNavigation(waitOptions),
>   page.click(selector, clickOptions),
> ]);
> ```

As a side point, it's probably better to do `waitForXPath` rather than `$x`, although this seems less likely the root problem. Don't forget to `await` all promises such as `browser.close()`.

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.goto('https://github.com/login');
  await page.type('#login_field', testLogin);
  await page.type('#password', testPassword);

  //    vvvvvvvvvvv
  await Promise.all([
    page.click('[name="commit"]'),
    page.waitForNavigation(),
  ]);
  const el = await page.waitForXPath('//h3[@class="text-normal"]');
                 //     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  //const el = await page.waitForSelector("h3.text-normal"); // ..or

  const text = await el.evaluate(el => el.textContent);
  console.log(text);
  //await browser.close();
  //^^^^^ missing await, or use finally as below
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close())
;
```

Additionally, if you're using Jest, once you get things working, you might want to move the `browser` and `page` management to `beforeEach`/`afterEach` or `beforeAll`/`afterAll` blocks. It's faster to use the same browser instance for all test cases, and pages can be opened and closed before/after each case.